# how to set fieldsets value should be whatever insert into my custom table column in magento2

Tags: magento2

I have create custom admin grid . In this i have create form.php file.In file it is satic value but i want the value should be comes from Database table (tbl_billing_cycle) and column name(billing_cycle)
form.php

```
`$fieldset->addField(
        'billingcycle',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'label' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
            'title' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
            'name' => 'billingcycle[]',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => [
                ["value" => "Once a day","label" => __("Once a day")],
                ["value" => "Once a week","label" => __("Once a week")],
                ["value" => "Once a month","label" => __("Once a month")],
                ["value" => "Once a year","label" => __("Once a year")],
            ],
        ]

    );`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$fieldset->addField(
        'billingcycle',
        'multiselect',
        [
            'label' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
            'title' => __('Select Billing Cycle'),
            'name' => 'billingcycle[]',
            'required' => true,
            'values' => $this->YOURFUNCTIONNAME(),
        ]

    );`
```

Now on the same file, create function like this :

```
public function YOURFUNCTIONNAME()
{
    // WRITE LOGIC TO GET OPTIONS FROM DATABASE AND RETURN AS ARRAY
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check below code.

add model dependency in your fieldset file to get billing cycle all options array.

**Form.php**

```
public function __construct(
        \Custom\Module\Model\Source\BillingCycle $billingCycle,
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        $this->billingCycle = $billingCycle;
        parent::__construct($context, $registry, $formFactory, $data);
    }

    protected function _prepareForm()
    {
        $allBillingCycle = $this->billingCycle->getAllOptions();
        
        $fieldset->addField(
            'type',
            'select',
            [
             'name' => 'type', 
             'label' => __('Warehouse Type'), 
             'values' => $allBillingCycle
            ]
        );
    }
```

in the model, file add your table model factory method to get the collection like

**Model\BillingCycle.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Model\Source;

class BillingCycle extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Table implements \Magento\Framework\Data\OptionSourceInterface
{

    protected $bankCodesFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Custom\Module\Model\[ModelName]Factory $billingCycleFactory
    ) {
        $this->billingCycleFactory = $billingCycleFactory;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAllOptions($withEmpty = true, $defaultValues = false) {

        $collection = $this->billingCycleFactory->create()->getCollection();

        $options = [];
        if ($withEmpty) {
            $options[] = ['label' => __('Please Select'), 'value' => ''];
        }
        foreach ($collection as $billingData) {
            $options[] = ['label' => $billingData->getBillingCycle(), 'value' => $billingData->getId()];
        }
        return $options;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

But the value is to be store as a entity_id in a Database. But i want BillingCycle value would be stored. then the code look like :
'value' => $billingData->getBillingCycle();
Is it Correct?

Comment: yes it's correct

Comment: If i want 'please select' option doesn't show in my admin grid form then what should i do?

Comment: if ($withEmpty) {
                $options[] = ['label' => __('Please Select'), 'value' => ''];
            }

Comment: remove above code

Comment: Thank you. can you solve this question ? click on the link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344854/how-to-create-required-fields-in-frontend-when-we-would-select-billing-cycle-the